# Where to save configuration data for custom CMS?

Tags: data-structures, configuration, content-management-system

What are the benefits of storing different configuration data of a website:

1. in database
2. in file
3. elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at a very brief glance, ignoring for now the differences between databases (databases could be anything from the behemoths of oracle and mssql to the super light mongodb, memcached, etc)

Pros of a database:

- multiple user access: you can be reading and writing simultaneously by different users.
- user access control: you get an extra layer for security to make sure you have control over who is accessing your data (usually, but not often. some databases dont have this)
- speed: databases performance at any realistic size of operations data absolutely destroys anything else.

Cons of a database:

- complexity. you have to put in way more work either talking to the database, or implementing an ORM (a layer that abstracts the nitty gritty details of communication away from you)
- an extra set of security holes to monitor and protect.

Pros of a textfile:

- it doesnt get any easier to store data than writing to a file.

Cons of a textfile:

- super insecure: if you misstep at all and don't think *everything* through, this is easy to get at.
- you have zero data integrity (i.e. what happens when multiple writes need to happen?). unless you're storing incredibly simple information (we're talking config-file sort of simple), you're going to get into situations where you have to modify a great deal of the file, maybe even re-write the whole thing regularly, which is slow.
- performance: disk IO is expensive. databases are super optimized to try and keep as much useful data in memory as possible.
- how do you find what you need? you're gonna have to structure your file somehow, XML or JSON, and you get a processing cost with that, especially if your data gets big.

I could go on, but to be honest, if you're doing a CMS, you're much better off with a proper database.

Obligatory footnote: don't create CMSs. we have enough that are constantly being peer reviewed and are secure, extensible, and super. creating your own from scratch is often just a recipe for disaster.